# Can I add suggestions for chrome.omnibox.onInputStarted.addListener?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am planning to write a Chrome extension to jump to a bookmark from the omnibox. I want to use the chrome omnibox APIs (see [Chrome omnibox APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/omnibox.html)). What the extension wants to do is:
1) type the search keyword "jb" (jump to bookmark) and type TAB to enter the extension;
2) before hitting any key, I want the omnibox give the suggestions from the bookmarks;
3) type any term in the omnibox; and update the suggestions.

The function is very simple. But I do not know how to implement the step #2 using the existing omnibox APIs. The method chrome.omnibox.onInputStarted.addListener does not accept to give suggestions. Suggestions are only allowed when some term is entered (via chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is an open issue related to onInputStarted — https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258911

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After pressing a tab key `chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener` is fired with an empty `text`, so you can return default suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your way and debugged the extension; but I found `chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener` was triggered before typing the TAB key (but after I entered the omnibox keyword). I suppose this was not expected. What do you think?

Comment: @adarliu Hm, you are right, it really is triggered before a tab key but after a keyword. But why does it matter if you just want to display default suggestions? I would think it makes even a better user experience if you can display suggestions before hitting tab key.

Comment: writing 'jb'+ 2 spaces fires the event too

Comment: As for now, it is not fired in Chrome